# Superhuman eyesight

Tags: human-biology, eyes, vision, human-eye

My ten year old son was reading car number plates that were too fast, too far away and at the wrong angle for any of us to read or even believe that it was possible for him to read. We thought he was lying as he reeled off the whole number plate and not just some. My husband went across the road to prove him wrong and get him to admit he was making it up but he wasn't. We even asked people in the restaurant and waiting staff for their opinion and everyone was blown away. I'm totally astonished and slightly freaked out by his sight and I'm hoping someone can explain for me.

**Specifics**

- I believe it was approx 20-25 metres away and I am under guessing.
- He had only 1 or 2 seconds as the cars drove left to right.
- Cars would be travelling 30/40 kmph along that road.
- We were sitting in the restaurant at night time so not in a car
  ourselves

Comment: Why is this off-topic or unclear? Please comment and we can work on the question. Aging is a hot topic in Bio.

Comment: You should provide additional details about approximate distance and speed of your car relative to other cars and size of the letters. Otherwise it would be difficult of anyone to ascertain if that was really an above-average perception.

Comment: He could perhaps be far-sighted.  How does he do with close-vision tasks like reading?

Comment: Thank you for all your responses! I believe it was approx 20-25 metres away and I am under guessing. He had only 1 or 2 seconds as the cars drove left to right. Cars would be travelling 30/40 kmph along that road. We were sitting in the restaurant at night time so not in a car ourselves

Comment: @Claire the distance may have helped with the speed - something further away has a lower angular speed and so is easier for the eyes to track (think of an airplane in the sky that is moving hundreds of mph but is very far away)

Comment: If memory has anything to do with it, I'll call - with high statistical sensitivity over specificity- Aspergers!

Comment: @jamesqf he is not as fluent with his reading as his 8 yr old sister although he can read and doesn't have trouble with pronunciation. I put it down to a girl/boy development thing....I have just booked an eye test because everyone's valuable comments are making me think about all possibilities....

Comment: @hello_there_andy memory?? Not in the case of the other night as it was there and then however he has an absolutely amazing memory too? He remembers things that he has seen that most people would not even bother to notice, ie that car (recollecting colour, model and plate) is always parked there, or, that lorry was the one that we saw driving down the highway when we were on our way to 'xyz' and it was raining really hard and u had a blue top on mum.....two yrs ago! Are you suggesting that eyesight and memory are an indication of aspergers?? I know little a out aspergers, maybe I should read

Comment: @Claire it really is a long-shot and I fear of making a hassle and run into a common cognitive bias related to self-diagnosis (see wiki: labeling theory). I'm a strong believer that society and expectations of people with disorders hinders them (see wiki: Daniel Kish for inspiration on what Humans can do w/o social expectations).

Comment: @hello_there_andy just briefly read symptoms for aspergers and there is not one symptom that I could say is possibly apparent. He's advanced beyond his years socially and has been from an early age, motor skills- fine, rides quads and bikes and horses from a young age...above average academically and extension in lots of subjects too. The only thing with social or behavioural interaction is his frustration at others and often not handling situations calmly enough?

Comment: I know what you mean, it appears that there are so many labels on lots of people compared to maybe the odd person years ago who was categorised as dyslexic if they couldn't spell and sometimes wonder what new labels will be born over the years ahead. I haven't ever felt alerted by anything enough to look into labelling for him however sometimes amazing traits such as this baffling eyesight and prob memory too, could also fall under such umbrellas as you've suggested. Maybe not aspergers but there may be another label for him!?

Comment: @Claire: I didn't mean reading ability, but reading (especially small print) as one example of a task that would require good close-up vision.  Other examples might be threading a needle, or assembling electronic parts on a circuit board.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "normal" visual acuity in the Anglosphere is the 20/20 vision which means that on a [Snellen chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snellen_chart) characters with 8,86 mm height can be read conveniently from a distance of approximately 6 m.

Now there are many known people who have very sharp eyes, having the doubled acuity of 20/10. This means they can discern characters of only 4,43 mm height from 6m.

The normal car signs in the EU (and I think it is not very different in size in other countries) is 75 mm. So a very good observer can discern number plates from a distance of
(75 mm / 4.46 mm) * 6 m = 100 meter or 109 yards, a normal observer from half the distance (50 m or 54 yards).

People are mostly not aware how their sight is deteriorating. Chris already said that the acuity goes down with age, but the other problem is that the lens is less flexible with age and therefore not able to focus a fast approaching car. Your son has no problem with that.

Sorry, I don't think your son is superhuman.

FOR THE CURIOUS: A rule of thumb is that normal sight has an acuity of 1 arcminute ('), the 60th part of a degree angle. This is a ratio of 0.000291 or 3 cm per 100 m (1 inch per 1 yard).
A character to read consists of parts, let's look for example at E. E has five vertical
sections and if you think about it, all other characters can be displayed if you have five
sections available. So Snellen set the height of the characters to 5 arcminutes and the stroke width to one arcminute. The patient looks from 20 ft (= 6.096 m) away. So the height
of the characters must be (5*0.000291)*6.096 = 8.866 mm

Comment: That's helpful seeing the distances thank you. I believe the distance was approx 20-25 metres away.

Answer (score 17):

**Short answer**

Visual acuity decreases with age. Your son's age is within the age range that visual acuities are best. Acuity starts to decrease from about age 45.

**Background**

**Visual acuity** (visual resolution) first **increases from birth up until around 4-6 years**. Note that in the following graph better acuities are represented by lower numbers (logMAR scale):

[image: acuity increase]
Source: [Pan et al, 2009](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2742505/)

**Visual acuity starts to decrease after 45 years.** The acuity of a 6-year old is about 1 on the scale in the next figure, showing the decline in acuity in older folks. Note that the graph starts at 30 years and acuities are already less than that in the former study's end point (look at the lower set of lines, i.e., the uncorrected ones). Also note that better acuities are higher up in the scale as this graph expresses acuities in decimal Snellen equivalents

[image: old age]
Source: [Gittings & Lozard, 1986](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3493168)

Hence, very likely, **your 10-year old's vision is not superhuman** (sorry!), it's just a lot better than yours. However, if you are younger than 45, we might conclude your acuity should be comparable and your son may be a visual rock-star - statistical outliers do exist and a simple visit to the optometrist will tell you! However, if you are near-sighted and are not using corrective vision aids (glasses or the likes) then this may be the cause of your lesser visual acuity.

**References**
[Pan et al., *Optom Vis Sci* 2009;**86**:607–12](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2742505/)
[Gittings & Lozard, *exp gerontol* 1986;**21**:423-33](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3493168)

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am 40 which is why we asked others in the restaurant and one guy was 18 and he laughed but I hadn't thought that he perhaps had terrible vision for his age! My 8 yr old daughter also couldn't decipher even one letter either so may be more important to check hers! It was approx 25 metres away, was dark and there was prob 1 or 2 seconds for him to capture it as it drove left to right and at a speed of 30/40kmph

Comment: @AliceD, Why did you protect this thread for? It's only 2700 views.

Comment: @Pacerier - not so much because of #views, but it has received multiple good quality answers and it was drawing in low-quality answers (since deleted and hidden from your view).

Answer (score 2):

He may have extreme acuity, or he may even have an extra cone type that allows him to see extra colors (and more color attunement may allow easier reading of those particular plates). But, you won't know anything for sure by asking on here. Take him to an ophthalmologist and let us know what the doc says! If you aren't 40+ and have 20/20 vision and he's seeing things better than you, then yeah, he probably is special!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My daughter is 8 and she could just see a blur and the 18 guy sitting next to us just laughed and said no chance he could see either but yes as per other responses above, I hadn't thought that everyone else compared may have particularly poor eye sight! I think I shall pop to have his eyes tested and will post on here the results

Comment: @Claire you should get in the habit of upvoting answers that have helped, some of us crave unicorn points

Comment: @hello_there_andy......how do I do that apart from singing praises in comment box!?

Comment: @Claire Just click the up arrow at the top left of the answer - but you need to collect some amount of points yourself first - so maybe it does not work yet - there would be a message explaining it when you try. You have 36 points "rep" ("reputation") currently. Three upvotes on your question would get you to 51, for example.

Comment: A functional male tetrachromat has yet to be found.  Finding one might count as "superhuman" vision, as much as any trait possessed by a human could be called such.

Comment: Hi everyone that kindly commented on my question a month ago. I have been to the optometrist this afternoon as suggested with my son and she has confirmed that he has 20/10 vision.